# Get node count from XML test case using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am having following XML for test cases.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestResultArray xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <TestResult>
      <Name>Test1</Name>
      <Date>9/15/2016</Date>
      <Time>4:09 PM</Time>
      <Id>697</Id>
      <Steps>
         <TestStep>
            <Number>2</Number>
            <Status>PASS</Status>
         </TestStep>
         <TestStep>
            <Number>3</Number>
            <Status>PASS</Status>
         </TestStep>
         <TestStep>
            <Number>4</Number>
            <Status>PASS</Status>
         </TestStep>
      </Steps>
   </TestResult>
   <TestResult>
      <Name>Test2</Name>
      <Date>9/15/2016</Date>
      <Time>4:09 PM</Time>
      <Id>697</Id>
      <Steps>
         <TestStep>
            <Number>2</Number>
            <Status>FAIL</Status>
         </TestStep>
         <TestStep>
            <Number>3</Number>
            <Status>PASS</Status>
         </TestStep>
         <TestStep>
            <Number>4</Number>
            <Status>PASS</Status>
         </TestStep>
      </Steps>
   </TestResult>
   <TestResult>
      <Name>Test3</Name>
      <Date>9/15/2016</Date>
      <Time>4:09 PM</Time>
      <Id>697</Id>
      <Steps>
         <TestStep>
            <Number>2</Number>
            <Status>FAIL</Status>
         </TestStep>
         <TestStep>
            <Number>3</Number>
            <Status>FAIL</Status>
         </TestStep>
         <TestStep>
            <Number>4</Number>
            <Status>FAIL</Status>
         </TestStep>
      </Steps>
   </TestResult>
</TestResultArray>
```

I am trying to get total number of test cases, number of passed and number of failed test cases.

Requirement is if any of the `<TestStep>` is FAIL the whole test case `<TestResult>` should be counted as FAIL.

I am able to get the total number of test case with

```
<tr>
<td>    <xsl:value-of select="count(TestResultArray/TestResult)" /> </td>
</tr>
```

How can I get total number of Passed and Failed test case `<TestResult>` (not `<TestStep>`) using XSLT ?

For the above XML example the output should be

```
Total Testcase = 3,
Passed = 1,
Failed = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="text" />

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:text>Total Testcase = </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="count(*)"/>
    <xsl:text>,&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>Passed = </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="count(*[not(Steps/*/Status = 'FAIL')])"/>
    <xsl:text>,&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>Failed = </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="count(*[Steps/*/Status = 'FAIL'])"/>
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your source XML, the following result is produced:

```
Total Testcase = 3,
Passed = 1,
Failed = 2
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks :)

Comment: You bet! Glad to help.